Facing difficulties with the XPATH text() function
My goal is to get the price text from the page.
When I use the XPATH
//*[@id="module_product_price_1"]/div/div/span

, it finds just one item. However, when I include the text() function
//*[@id="module_product_price_1"]/div/div/span/text()

, it discovers two items. The first one is hidden, while the second one holds the visible text.
Here is the webpage.
Here is the element


<div id="module_product_price_1" class="pdp-block module"><div class="pdp-mod-product-price"><img src="https://img.lazcdn.com/g/gcp/lazada/id00780-480-72.jpg_500x500q80.jpg_.webp" alt="promotion" class="pdp-mod-product-price-topbanner"><div class="pdp-product-price"><span class="notranslate pdp-price pdp-price_type_normal pdp-price_color_orange pdp-price_size_xl">$30.00</span></div></div></div>




What do you mean by "the first one is hidden"? When I inspect that page, I only see one text() child node under that span. What is the value of the other text()? Is it just whitespace or carriage return?

Inspecting
$x('//*[@id="module_product_price_1"]/div/div/span/text()')

shows an extra, empty text node as the first child of the targeted span.
It can easily be ignored by taking the string value of the targeted span and normalizing the whitespace via normalize-space():
normalize-space(//*[@id="module_product_price_1"]/div/div/span)


I don't see the extra node in the Safari web page inspector.

@MichaelKay: I believe sibling text node consolidation is implementation-dependent.   On OP's target page, Chrome's DevTools console (Version 124.0.6367.62 (Official Build) (arm64)) evaluation of the $x('//*[@id="module_product_price_1"]/div/div/span/text()') yielded an array of two text nodes, consistent with OP's observation.  I investigated no further than that.

Implementation-dependent in the sense that some implementations conform to the standard and others don't, not in the sense that the standard allows implementations to vary. The XPath data model does not allow adjacent sibling text nodes.
